# Why is it ok to put all the elements to the exact power if they had different power before that?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

The question could sound messy, so will demonstrate what I mean. I'm going through Algorithm course from Stanford ([full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nPA.png)), when the teacher makes the proof for $O(n^k)$ notation:

$$T(n) = a_kn^k + ... + a_1n+a_0$$
$$T(n) = O(n^k)$$
$$c = |a_k| + ... + |a_1|+|a_0|$$
$$n_0 = 1$$

And, when making the proof he starts with:
$$T(n) \le |a_k|n^k + ... + |a_1|n+|a_0|$$

But then decides to power all the elements to $n^k$:
$$T(n) \le |a_k|n^k + ... + |a_1|n^k+|a_0|n^k$$

So, my question is - why it's possible? It's not like he multiplied both parts of inequality, he just added a lot to the right part, but the inequality still valid for some reason. Any link or short answer will do, need just to get a general idea.

Comment: I reckon that $n^{k-1}\le n^k$, $n^{k-2}\le n^k$, etc.

Comment: If $b\ge a$, and you add a lot to $b$, is there any way that the resulting number could be **less** than $a$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I mean, yeah, totally agree, but what point in the proof so? So, until you adding surely positive elements, so the number grows, the equation still stands. Yup, sounds logical. Could you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b\ge a$, and you add a lot to $b$, is there any way that the resulting number could be **less** than $a$?

The point of doing it here is to be able to pull out the common factor of $n^k$ to see that

$$T(n)\le(|a_k|+\ldots+|a_1|+|a_0|)n^k\;:$$

the factor $|a_k|+\ldots+|a_1|+|a_0|$ is a constant that doesn’t depend on $n$. If we call it $M$, we can say that $T(n)\le Mn^k$ for all sufficiently large $n$, which is exactly what we need in order to conclude that $T(n)$ is $O(n^k)$.

Comment: Thanks again :)

Comment: @sortas: You’re welcome!